# Graphical models: 2 complete graphs with different v-structure

Tags: graph-theory

How do you construct 2 **different** complete directed graphs which have different v-structures ???

I am also a bit confused about the definition of a v-structure. A graph that has a v-structure must satisify: $$ X \; \rightarrow \;Z \;\leftarrow\;Y$$  . A v-structure has to look like the above, right?

Comment: The punctuation for displayed equations needs to be included inside the double dollar signs; otherwise, as you can see, it gets placed on the following text line. (By the way, what's the added value of the second and third question marks?)

Comment: A quick google search didn't turn up a definition for v-structure.  If you include the definition in your question then I suspect you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In a complete graph, there are no v-structures! A v-structure is a triple of nodes $X_1, X_2, X_3$ with edges $X_1 \to X_2 \leftarrow X_3$ such that $X_1$ and $X_3$ are *not adjacent*. But in a complete graph, all nodes are adjacent. So trivially, all complete graphs over the same set of variables have the same (empty) set of v-structures.

Also, contrary to Ittay Weiss's answer, complete directed graphs are allowed in the context of DAGs. Only directed cycles are forbidden, not undirected cycles. It is easy to construct a complete DAG. Simply order all the nodes, then add edges from each node to all the nodes that follow it in the order. All the nodes are now adjacent and there are no directed cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to what Koller calls a $v$-structure in a DAG in her course of probabilistic graphical models. A $v$-structure consists of three nodes $v_1,v_2,v_3$ together with two edges, from $v_1,v_3$ to $v_2$. These are used in modeling information and causation flow (ideas that go back to Pearl).

As this notion is typically given in the context of a DAG, complete graphs are not allowed (since they typically contain cycles). Maybe you mean to consider maximal DAGs, in which case you can of course find many different $v$-structures in a given DAG, provided the DAG is big enough. I hope this answers your question, if not please provide some more context.